# reloading .bashrc file inside WSL2

Tags: wsl-2, windows-11

Im using Windows 11 with WSL 2 Ubuntu distro and I having a problem that I have to run `source ~/.bashrc` file every time when I start a new terminal session to reload my environment variables.

Is there a way to reload this automatically when I start a session?

Thankyou,

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/2067

Answer (score 0):

Typically your WSL2 will load the .bashrc file of the account you login
automatically, maybe you can try something like this:

1. check the **/etc/wsl.conf** file on your WSL2 distro, and determine the user you want to login when boot up, if you do not have any security worry, choose 'root' as default, and add this into **wsl.conf**:

```
[user]
default=root
```

2. maybe your .bashrc file has:

   - wrong file name;
   - wrong location;
3. lastly, use the method in **1.** to create a new account and login, check if that account can load .bashrc file automatically.